# FindFirstFileW Issue - How to Convert 'LPWIN32_FIND_DATA *' to 'LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW'

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have implemented the following function to list the contents of a directory but when I compile and linked the program, the compiler gives the following two errors to me:

> error C2664: 'HANDLE FindFirstFileW(LPCWSTR,LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'LPWIN32_FIND_DATA *' to 'LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW'
>
> error C2664: 'BOOL FindNextFileW(HANDLE,LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'LPWIN32_FIND_DATA *' to 'LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW'

How can I fix this code to work with the Unicode format:

```
bool FmListDirectoryContents(LPWSTR arg_path_dir)
{
    LPWIN32_FIND_DATA wfd_Data;
    wchar_t c_Path[2048];

    wprintf(c_Path, "%s\\*", arg_path_dir);

    HANDLE h_Find = FindFirstFileW(c_Path, &wfd_Data);

    if (h_Find != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        PrintColorful(5, L"\n\t%s\t\t\t%s", "-----------", "-----------");
        PrintColorful(5, L"\n\t%s\t\t\t%s", "File Size", "File Name");
        PrintColorful(5, L"\n\t%s\t\t\t%s\n", "-----------", "-----------");

        do {
            ULONGLONG FileSize = wfd_Data->nFileSizeHigh;
            FileSize <<= sizeof(wfd_Data->nFileSizeHigh) * 8;
            FileSize |= wfd_Data->nFileSizeLow;
            printf("\n\t%llu\t\t\t\t%s", FileSize, wfd_Data->cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFileW(h_Find, &wfd_Data));

        printf("\n\n");
        FindClose(h_Find);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `LPWIN32_FIND_DATA` -> `LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW` and `%s` -> `` -> `%ls`

Comment: Very common mistake. You see that you need to pass a pointer, so you declare a pointer. That's the mistake. You must instead declare an object, and then pass the address of that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `FindFirstFileW()` and `FindNextFileW()` a pointer to a pointer to a `WIN32_FIND_DATA`, but that is not what they are expecting, hence the compiler errors.  They want a pointer to a `WIN32_FIND_DATAW` instead.

You are also misusing `printf()` and `wprintf()`.

Try this:

```cpp
bool FmListDirectoryContents(LPWSTR arg_path_dir)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW wfd_Data; // <-- not LPWIN32_FIND_DATA!
    wchar_t c_Path[2048];

    swprintf(c_Path, L"%s\\*", arg_path_dir); // <-- not wprintf!

    HANDLE h_Find = FindFirstFileW(c_Path, &wfd_Data);

    if (h_Find != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        PrintColorful(5, L"\n\t%s\t\t\t%s", "-----------", "-----------");
        PrintColorful(5, L"\n\t%s\t\t\t%s", "File Size", "File Name");
        PrintColorful(5, L"\n\t%s\t\t\t%s\n", "-----------", "-----------");

        do {
            ULARGE_INTEGER FileSize;
            FileSize.HighPart = wfd_Data->nFileSizeHigh;
            FileSize.LowPart = wfd_Data->nFileSizeLow;
            wprintf(L"\n\t%llu\t\t\t\t%s", FileSize.QuadPart, wfd_Data->cFileName); // <-- not printf!
        }
        while (FindNextFileW(h_Find, &wfd_Data));

        FindClose(h_Find);
        wprintf(L"\n\n");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You choose that you will specify to use Unicode API manually, so you have to use `LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW` (with explicit suffix `W`) instead of `LPWIN32_FIND_DATA`.

Also, the 2nd argument of `FindFirstFileW` and `FindNextFileW` are type `LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW`, so it is wrong to pass a pointer to `LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW`.
`LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW` is already a pointer to `WIN32_FIND_DATAW`, so you have to allocate a variable having type `WIN32_FIND_DATAW` and pass a pointer to that.

references:

- [WIN32_FIND_DATAW (minwinbase.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-win32_find_dataw)
- [FindFirstFileW function (fileapi.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew)
- [FindNextFileW function (fileapi.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew)

Comment: BTW I'd rather use `WIN32_FIND_DATA *wfd_Data` instead of `LPWIN32_FIND_DATA wfd_Data`, then it's less likely you'll mess things up.

Comment: Indeed, the `LP` prefix is short for *"long pointer"*. The distinction between long pointers and near pointers was relevant in 16-bit Windows. Today, with a flat memory model, a pointer is just a pointer. See [pointer types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/windows-coding-conventions#pointer-types) for additional information.